# How to disable Compiz in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: compiz

So I was learning python, blah blah blah I switched over to Windows so I could play Minecraft(I forgot how to enable the .jar to executable) and then I switched back and no my computer is so laggy, and according to System Monitor its Compiz. No idea what it is or anything, I just need to disable it, or uninstall it because it is not doing anything AT ALL. It was not this laggy before and its very undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Install another desktop that doesn't need hardware acceleration like XFCE or LXDE

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```